# dynamic type parameter to method that returns void in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

The code below generates exception:

Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'

```
var m = M((dynamic)d);  //Exception thrown here
private void M(Int32 n) { Console.WriteLine("M(Int32): " + n); }
```

I think that null should be assigned to the m variable instead of exception.

Any idea?

**Edit**

Please note that below generates compile time error

```
dynamic result = M(1);//compile time error:  Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'dynamic'

private void M(Int32 n) { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally questions like this are answered with a specification reference showing that the compiler / run-time is actually doing the right thing. In this case, the relevant section of the spec (7.2.2) is relatively silent. It basically says that the exact details are implementation-specific.

However, I would argue that it's doing the right thing: if you think of dynamic typing as roughly translating to letting the compiler operate in the same way, but using the *actual* types of expressions as they are at execution time, then it's entirely reasonable to have an execution time error. The normal compiler behaviour when calling a void method is to prohibit using it as the right-hand side of an assignment expression, so why should that change just because the binding is done at execution time?

Comment: Hi Jon, Thank you for your advice. When i debug it, the exception is thrown from the first line. I think I agree with you. Because a method that returns void cannot assign to any type, which should be the same reason for a dynamic type. Please refer to my opening post for the example.


I came across the question on CLR via C#, on p151. Does it mean something else?

Comment: @Pingpong: The problem is that the method being called isn't known at compile-time, which is why there's not a compile-time error - it's being bound dynamically, so the compiler acts as if it's possible that there'll be an M method which *does* return something. It sounds like it's basically an error in CLR via C# - that page may have been written before the final release. I know I had to change C# in Depth due to changes in dynamic binding between one of the betas and another.

Comment: Thanks. Your book is also a highly recommended book.